# Bgcolor not working in while loop

Tags: javascript, html, web, background-color

Although I know that `bgcolor`  is not the best thing to use to change a web page's color dynamically, the CSS route does not appear to allow numbers like `bgcolor` does (unless I am mistaken). My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script>
      while(1===1){
        confirm("You will click this";)
        document.write("<h1>HELLO</h1>");
        document.bgcolor = bgcolor;
      } 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

I also know that my code is in an infinite loop.

Comment: Any particular reason why you need an infinite loop?

Comment: Also, where have you defined `bgcolor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try document.body.style.background instead of document.bgcolor?

Also, I have to ask, why would you need the infinite loop there?

Answer (score 0):

you can look into this for reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.bgColor

where it says:

> **document.bgColor** is deprecated in DOM Level 2 HTML. The recommended
>   alternative is use of the CSS style background-color which can be
>   accessed through the DOM with **document.body.style.backgroundColor**.
>   Another alternative is document.body.bgColor, although this is also
>   deprecated in HTML 4.01 in favor of the CSS alternative.

so if you go to console and write like this, color will be changed

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "darkblue"
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with what others have said, it appears you have a syntax error on line 7, which may be causing you issues; the semicolon should come after the parenthesis.